# Resize metadata navigation pane using code

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a basic list with metadata navigation enabled. Now I have a navigation pane on the left side of the list and it's resizable with drag and drop. How can I resize this left menu with javascript or css (or similar)? I need to set the initial size a few pixels wider.

Answer (score 2):

Default size for left menu is 155px.

You can use this CSS code to scale the left-nav to 200px (replace with your own value):

```
body #s4-leftpanel{
width:200px;
}
.s4-ca{
margin-left:205px;
}
```